# PHP Mail function delay

Tags: php, email

When I send email with PHP function on my custom PHP website hosted with GoDaddy, the email is delayed and I receive it after some time.

Is there any way to get the email instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. 
Because a smtp server send mail with a queue process. I suppose that you are on a shared server. So other people use the mail() function to.
Moreover you forget that a smtp server will send to another smtp server..... until it touch the smtp server of your provider (exemple gmail) and it can take a lot of time and be lost in the process to.

Comment: Can you please guide for the best option

Comment: There no best options per se. You will have always a delay. You can try some mail service. But it will never be instantaneous.

Comment: @TalhaAslam, you can use SMTP servers like Google, Postmark and sendgrid.